# Is it possible to use php spreadsheet without composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Is it possible to run php spreadsheet without composer? If there is, how to do it?

Comment: composer is just a tool that manages your dependencies, you can download the code of php spreadsheet and use the library independently in your code.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo can u elaborate more. i want to use php office/spreadsheet without using composer. i don't know how to explain it. I just want to create excel file using php but not using composer. Is it possible?

Comment: composer doesn't have to do anything with spreadsheet. You need to study first what is composer and why is used.

Comment: Besides that: is there any good reason not to use Composer to install packages?

Comment: Composer just provides an easy way to install PHP software packages such as phpoffice, and thousands of others, into your application.  If you want to install the package another way (such as just copy and pasting the code files) then that's up to you. It's completely separate from the way you actually use that package to create an excel file.